# how to navigate one webview two another webview from different .xib files

Tags: ios, webview

i have one webview in

```
 1. webview1 
       -webview1.xib
       - webview1delegate.h
       - webview1delegate.m 
       - webview1Controller.h
       - webview1Controller.h
  2. webview2
       -webview2controller.h
       -webview2controller.m
```

fiels i want to specify the url in webview2controller.m file that want to load in webview1.xib file webview.. anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On webView delegate

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
   if([[request.URL description] isEqualToString:@"your link"])
     //load other xib
}
```

Comment: i want to line address from another .m file